# Php artisan command returns error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan commands are not working for laravel project and return the following error after composer update.

In Collection 2.php line 11:

Class Illuminate\Support\Collection contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Support\Enumerable::countBy)

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?  what is Collection 2.php?

Comment: What usually helps is removing the `vendor` folder and running `composer install` again. If it doesn't help remove `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file. Then run `composer update`.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I tried everything since the past few hours but nothing worked. Please add this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank You